# how to animate views change views hierarchy using autolayout?

Tags: ios, animation, view, subview

I have superview called self.myMainView

In that view I have three subviews: UIView *view1 (green view), UIView *view2 (grey view), UIImageView *view3

I want to animation moving of view 3

and when view 3 is finished this animation than I want to change view hierarchy, like on example screenshots.

Here is example images:

[image: before:]

[image: and after our manipulations it must be]

Comment: @matt this image view for example, how this can be valuable? View 3 can behave incorrectly?

Comment: so that I can try to reproduce the problem. Working on it...

Comment: hey matt if you could help me I can make a model with all valuable code for you, do you need this?

Comment: no, I've reproduced the problem! Your description was good. Now I'm looking for a solution...

Comment: I figured it out! It's because you've got autolayout turned on in your storyboard

Comment: @matt oh, yes it is matt you right, that is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the constraints of view 3 which doesn't change after animation and when we wants to manipulate the view hierarchy, animation is stopped work properly. Matt said about that in his answer, also he provide a solution from his great book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout 
thank you for that Matt.

I change this solution a little and decide to post it here for anyone who will need this. But if you want to understand this better I highly recommend you to read chapter about animation from book, link is above.

First, we need to animate our movement of view 3, then change our constraints and only after this change the view hierarchy. In the book a found several ways to done this, but this one is seemed to me the best:

```
layout = -35.0; //  new constraint constant of self.view3

NSArray *constraintsForAnimation = self.myMainView.constraints; // all constraints of superview 

NSUInteger indexOfconstraintsAttribute = [constraintsForAnimation
indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){ // get index of constraint of view 3

    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = obj;


    return (([constraint.firstItem isEqual: self.view3])) ? idx : NO; // return this index if we found constraint of view 3

}];


constraint.constant = layout; // changing the constraint of view3 

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ // animation
   [self.view3 layoutIfNeeded]; // apply new constraints to view3
}];


[self.myMainView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:3 withSubviewAtIndex:4];// toggle view 1 with view 2
```

We move our view 3 only with help of constraints, we don't set frame or centre view property. 
Okay, we done with and this working like as I want. Hope this help you too.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is the normal, standard way to change the layering order of views. So the problem is not this, but in your words "But, it violates my animation" and "crushing my animation". The problem, then, is with your animation, if it can be "violated" and "crushed" by rearranging the layers. However, you do not provide, in your question, any information about the animation! Yet that is clearly the heart of the problem.

EDIT: Now that you've posted the animation code, I was able to test, and I see what the problem is. The problem is that you are using autolayout.

`view3` is positioned by constraints. When you animate the position of `view3`, you violate those constraints, but this does not become immediately evident. But when you exchange the layering order of `view1` and `view2`, layout is performed! The constraints on `view3` are then enforced. Since those constraints did not change, we see `view3` back where you originally had it.

The simplest solution is to turn off autolayout if you don't need it. Otherwise, you will have to change the constraints, after the animation or as part of the animation. In fact, you can reposition `view3` by animating its positional constraints. I describe all this in my book, here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_animation_and_autolayout

Comment: thank you!) Yesterday I read a chapter from your book about views :) thank for your work you doing it great!

Comment: I hope this section of the book will help you. It starts with an example very similar to yours, where the view "jumps back" to where it started. Then I give various solutions to the problem.

Comment: hello matt, I want to ask you about one issue that is in you code from your book, I used code that is animate the change in the constraint that positions the view, and here is code that have this issue and throw the exception: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 128552240 beyond bounds [0 .. 17]'` the code is: `NSUInteger indexOfconstraintsAttribute = [constraintsForAnimation indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){...}` xcode worried about type NSUInteger it must be NSIndexSet why?

Comment: I made a mistake in previous comment and in my code, I change `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` to `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`, but Xcode is still throw exception. same error: `2013-04-25 18:05:31.948 MyFirstApp[8676:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds [0 .. 18]'` I don't know what's going wrong

Comment: The comments are not a good place for a second question; instead, just ask a new question! That way you can show your code properly etc.

Comment: I solve this problem few seconds ago, but I have question directly to you Matt, I don't understand something in your examples thats in you book, I don't know can I send you a direct message here?

Comment: You can start a chat room, or you can just email me (it's easy to figure out my email if you follow the links long enough).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is switch which of your 2 subviews are on top of one another, can you simply use `[UIView bringSubviewToFront:]` rather than directly messing with the order of your subview array?  That might solve the animation problems.  The other thing I would try is put an `if( finished )` around your call to `exchangeSubviewAtIndex` to make sure it doesn't interfere with the other views being animated.

Comment: `bringSubviewToFront` is not suitable for my purposes, I already tried it, but I'll try `if(finished)` right now

Comment: hm okay I'll poke around and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: No problem!  Glad you got it sorted out.